# Extending a holomorphic map continously

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $\Omega = \mathbb{C} \setminus [-1, 1]$.

a) Give an example of a non-constant bounded holomorphic function on $\Omega$.

b) Show that such a function cannot be extended continuously to all of $\mathbb{C}$.

So, part a) is easy. We consider the Joukowski map $F(z)=\frac{1}{2} (z+1/z)$, which maps the inside of the unit disk to $\Omega$. Then solving for the inverse and choosing the correct sign of the square root, we get a map from $\Omega$ to the unit disk.

However, I am stuck on part b). If the map extended to a continuous map, would it be necessarilly holomorphic in the entire plane so I could apply Liouville's theorem? What are some general statements that can be made about extending maps continously to the boundary?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you would have an entire function via Morera's theorem

Comment: I can see that. Since the image would be bounded, I can approximate any curve around one of the points on the segment by a union of three curves, one above the segment, one below, and one having points of the segment, but since the function is bounded I can make that part as small as I want, while the integrals over the other curves are zero since they are in the holomorphic part. Thanks!